# Replace string in sms template string

Tags: php, mysql

I have following Template string in mysql which i fetch through php.

> $msg = "Dear $contacts-salutation$ $contacts-firstname$ $contacts-lastname$, 
>   Wish you a very Happy Birthday!! Best Regards, Team";

I want to replace $contacts-***_*_** $ with variable which is exist in other mysql table. but i can not replace it ?

How can i replace string in string?

Comment: `str_replace` for php, `REPLACE()` for mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

${contacts}-dadasdsdasd

Comment: Hi Tiago how can i use '${contacts}-dadasdsdasd' because i cant change parameter values in template(db table)

Comment: hummm... well.. the solution can be str_replace

Comment: $smsMsg = str_replace('$contacts-firstname$', $row['firstname'], $row2['body']);
  $smsMsg = str_replace('$contacts-lastname$', $row['lastname'], $smsMsg);
  $smsMsg = str_replace('$contacts-salutation$', $row['salutation'], $smsMsg);  
  $smsMsg = str_replace('$leads-salutation$', $row['salutation'], $smsMsg);
  $smsMsg = str_replace('$leads-firstname$', $row['firstname'], $smsMsg);
  $smsMsg = str_replace('$leads-lastname$', $row['lastname'], $smsMsg);
  $sms_mobile = str_replace("+91","",$row['mobile']);
  echo $sms_mobile ." |". " " . $smsMsg."<br>";